# stream data compression in parquet

Tags: python, pyspark, parquet

I have data frame with accelerometer data and i'm trying to get decent parquet compression.

The encoding parquet use is "PLAIN,BIT_PACKED" i thought that using Delta encoding is more suitable algorithm but i do not find a way to do it ( i tried also fastparquet & pyarrow)

Does someone know what is the efficient way to store that kind of data ?

```
    df.head()

        TS  id  x   y   z
    0   1520937997111   1038186 0.37633 0.45720 -0.77930
    1   1520937997147   1038186 0.42979 0.53668 -0.79269
    2   1520937997167   1038186 0.39102 0.48924 -0.84486
    3   1520937997187   1038186 0.42815 0.41864 -0.84589
    4   1520937997207   1038186 0.35527 0.44098 -0.81427


    df.dtypes
    TS      int64
    id      int64
    x     float64
    y     float64
    z     float64
    dtype: object

    schema = StructType([
        StructField('TS',LongType(),False),
        StructField('id',StringType(),False),
        StructField('x',FloatType(),False),
        StructField('y',FloatType(),False),
        StructField('z',FloatType(),False)
        ])
    df_hf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df, schema)
    df_hf.write.option("compression","gzip").mode("overwrite").parquet("tst.parquet")


    parquet-tools meta tst.parquet

    row group 1: RC:43669 TS:1353947 OFFSET:4
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TS:           INT64 GZIP DO:0 FPO:4 SZ:77859/349399/4.49 VC:43669 ENC:PLAIN,BIT_PACKED
    id:           BINARY GZIP DO:0 FPO:77863 SZ:1022/480403/470.06 VC:43669 ENC:PLAIN,BIT_PACKED
    x:            FLOAT GZIP DO:0 FPO:78885 SZ:134681/174715/1.30 VC:43669 ENC:PLAIN,BIT_PACKED
    y:            FLOAT GZIP DO:0 FPO:213566 SZ:131936/174715/1.32 VC:43669 ENC:PLAIN,BIT_PACKED
    z:            FLOAT GZIP DO:0 FPO:345502 SZ:130390/174715/1.34 VC:43669 ENC:PLAIN,BIT_PACKED
```

Comment: Could you try including encoding in your schema like `StructField("a",LongType(),True, {'encoding':'delta'})`

Comment: I added the metadata and also disable the dictionary but there is no change. sqlContext.setConf('parquet.enable.dictionary', False)

Comment: @alon_r we've been trying to figure this out for ages. I have an open question directly to Databricks about it and have seen conflicting information on the Parquet JIRA. Did you ever figure it out?